# How to enable Grid in User Ortho View?

Tags: 3d-view

I need the grid to be enabled after rolling a side view with Shift Numpad 4/Numpad 6. How do I enable it?
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: ? are you talking about the reference 3d grid, by default on global XY plane? It should be always visible, not depending on the view... or maybe I didn't get what you're asking... try to add an image of your setup...

Comment: hi m.ardito! I've added a screenshot with some annotations. Hope it makes it clear.

Comment: The grid is here I think you just can't see it because it's flat (like the green line in he right side of your image). Maybe model from the top to see the grid and rotate your model at the end?

Comment: Ok, I got what you meant after adding that image, thanks. I think there's no way to visualize the grid in that case, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

In blender 2.81, when in an orthographic view, you can enable the grid in Viewport Overlays:

[image: Grid option in the Viewport Overlays menu]

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

The Grid, as opposed to the XY Floor, is only available in the **set** orthographic views..(*Front*, *Top*, etc.) Even if a User orthographic view happens to be looking straight down a World axis, Blender doesn't check for that.

I often use this feature to quickly get rid of the grid for a moment, by tapping <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> on the numpad.